# Implement captcha in android?

Tags: android, captcha

Hello every I am working on android application where i need to implement captcha with my android application I want to create captcha which we are using in web applications. I found some answer about simple-captcha and j-captcha, but how to use it with android applications, I not find any tutorial which is use full for in this case.

Any idea or solution for this?

thanks in advance

Comment: i already have this but not working in my case .